# Laravel 8 Fortify binding implementations of the PasswordResetResponse contracts within register method of FortifyServiceProvider not working

Tags: laravel-8, fortify

I am trying to customize the redirect of PasswordResetResponse but its not working. Currently within register method of FortifyServiceProvider I have following code

```
 $this->app->instance(PasswordResetResponse::class, new class implements PasswordResetResponse{
        public function toResponse($request): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
        {
            return redirect(route('admin.login));
        }
    });
```

Redirect responses for login and logout(LoginResponse, LogoutResponse) are working fine but PasswordResetResponse is not working. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

maybe

```
 $this->app->instance(...);
 ↓
 $this->app->singleton(...);
```

Comment: Finally something worked!